# CSS: Bad Hover Performance on Webkit, Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, hover

I'm trying to get this css hovers smoothly in Webkit. It runs fine in Firefox, even IE. But in Chrome and Safari it acts awfully laggy.

```
.ark-kutucuk:hover {
z-index: 10;
width: 50%;
}

.ark-kutucuk {
 position: relative;
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 background-position: top;
 background-size: cover;
}

.ark-kutucuk:hover > [class|="nov"] {
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(360deg);
max-width: 100%;
}

.ark-kutucuk:hover > [class="ark-yazı-kutu"] {
opacity: 0;
}
```

Best Regards

Edit: The Site http://mindlessranger.byethost22.com/ I'm on "beta" now so byethost

Comment: please add relevant HTML or even better, a fiddle so people can test your code

Comment: Runs fine for me, am I missing something? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8sqrvs1/)

Comment: I have add the site look at there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove

```
transition-delay: 500ms
transition-duration: 500ms;
```

then add

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Explanation: removing additional styles, using one line declaration and then using hardware acceleration (the translate3d part) to make animations run smoother. You can adjust values as needed

Comment: This is much much better thanks for the hardware "acceraletion" part but it doesn't work for the elements which I use transform before.

Comment: Look at the "Alicization" div it is still laggy because it have much more element inside and those elements have transform before. So acceleration can't work. But Thanks, I have to sleep its 2 a.m. in my country. Bye